# why is bitcoin leveldb separated in so many small pieces?

Tags: leveldb

Currently I could see `1418` ldb files on my box, from 210040.ldb to 215423.ldb (some missing).

- Why are they separated in this way?
- I want to read the leveldb using golang, but I don't know which one should I use.
- Can I load them altogether?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment I try out creating my own leveldb I understand.. The `chainstate` folder itself is the entry point of the database; all the files within it are just the data.

This is what the data looks like after I put some dummy data

[image]

Comment: If you want to add more information, please edit the question rather than posting an answer :)

Comment: Apologies if this was intended as an answer, it didn't seem to fully address all the points of the question :)

Comment: @MeshCollider np. :) Actually the 3 questions can be answered by this one. The separation of .ldb files has nothing to do with bitcoin, it's just the way leveldb stores the data. I hope this learning can help save others' time.